# NiFi - Error with PutDatabaseRecord while upsert with one column

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to insert or update table based on a unique key. But `PutDatabaseRecord` processor is throwing error: **source for a multiple-column UPDATE item must be a sub-SELECT or ROW() expression**

However no error is thrown with multiple columns. This error is only with one column

Simple User table with id(PK) and name columns.

Here is my `PutDatabaseRecord` config:

[PutDatabaseRecord config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfbi5.png)

Here is my JSONTreereader:
[JSONTreereader config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMBWK.png)

Please help me with this issue

Comment: Can you share your PutDatabaseRecord configuration, as well as the table information (columns, primary keys, etc.)?

Comment: @mattyb Updated my original question with the details you asked for

Comment: Are you sure the `id` column is a primary key and has no duplicates?

Comment: Yes, and that id comes from source. So, if id already exists I'm updating name(upsert) @mattyb

Comment: Anyone found solution to this?